# The attribute 'FactoryMethod' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I am complete newbie to WPF and XAML and I am already regretting trying to learn it in the first place. I am not sure why the error in running the code below, I copied it directly from a WPF 4 unleashed book. If any of you guys can help me in figuring this our I will owe you guys a big favor:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:Person="clr-namespace:Src"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="354" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <Label Name="lblText" Foreground="BlanchedAlmond" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
      Test
    </Label>
    <Label x:FactoryMethod="System:Guid.NewGuid">Test2</Label>    
    <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
      <Person:Person FirstName="Deepak" LastName="Sharma"></Person:Person>
      <Person:Person FirstName="Nidhi" LastName="Sharma"></Person:Person>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`x:FactoryMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795381.aspx) is a [XAML 2009 feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007.aspx), which according to the documentation are not supported in markup compiled XAML.

> In WPF, you can use XAML 2009 features, but only for XAML that is not WPF markup-compiled. Markup-compiled XAML and the BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 language keywords and features.

Besides that `Guid.NewGuid` does not return a `Label` so i am not sure how this is supposed to work out in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry for the incorrect code but I am more concerned about the FactoryMethod. I am not sure why the factory method is still not available in a WPF application on .NET 4.0 building in Visual Studio 2010. Do you mean I have to use something like XAMLPad or some third party application to use this.

Comment: You have to generate the control from uncompiled XAML, this could be done with the `XamlReader` for example, but seriously **don't bother with it until it is supported in compiled XAML**, it's fairly useless otherwise.

Comment: I am getting a similar error using the x:Arguments tag. Is it because of the same issue?

Comment: Yes, also XAML 2009, belongs to `FactoryMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

H.B's answer is accurate. Since you said you're reading WPF4 Unleashed, refer to page table 2.2 starting on page 67.

Here is what MSDN has to say about it:
`"In WPF, you can use XAML 2009 features but only for XAML that is not markup-compiled. Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and features."`

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).